# admin only areas in django + app engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

i am using django-norel for deploying to app engine.what which one would be a better solution for admin only areas ?
1) using app.yaml to define admin only areas
2) writing a middleware for google userservice

update : 
there is this entry

```
   - url: /.*
  script: djangoappengine/main/main.py
```

in ap.yaml doesn't that mean that all pages will be handled by main.py
in case i am using `login:admin` how would that affect the current functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a third-party admin area I use [appengine_admin](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-admin/). 
To pass the variable whether current user is admin to the template I also found the following convenient

```
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, {''admin':users.is_current_user_admin()..
```

then in template admin parts display towards admin with tag

```
{% if admin %} ... admin stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

Use app.yaml for admin areas because `login: admin` is an easy and clean solution.

If you want moderator functionality on public pages you can use [users.is_current_user_admin()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/functions.html#is_current_user_admin).

**Update:** You can't use `login: admin` to restrict access to some functions in one file. If you want to use it you have to create a separate admin.py file or something.

You could also try to create a function decorator like @admin_required. [Here's](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py) an example for @login_required.

Here's the part that you'd have to change:

```
user = users.get_current_user()
if not user:
   self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
   return
else:
   handler_method(self, *args)
```

to

```
if not users.is_current_user_admin():
    self.redirect(denied_url)
    return
else:
    handler_method(self, *args)
```